# Compare amount of files in 2 directories and their subdirectories

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system, compare, comparison, os.walk

I have 2 direcrories: IMAGES_PATH and JSON_PATH. IMAGES_PATH contains images. JSON_PATH contains json files. I know that amount of images must be equal to amount of json files. Each directory contains same subdirectories. I mean that names of folders are the same. I know how to count all files in given directory:

```
    import os, os.path
    total = 0
    #IMAGES_PATH, JSON_PATH are given
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(IMAGES_PATH):
        total += len(files)
```

Is there any way to compare amount of files in IMAGES_PATH\all subdirectories with amount of files in JSON_PATH\all subdirectories and return list of directories\subdirectories, which contain different amount of file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the directory structure of `IMAGES_PATH` and `JSON_PATH` really is the same, I like using `zip` to synchronize the search:

```
for a,b in zip(os.walk(IMAGES_PATH), os.walk(JSON_PATH)):
  current_image_dir, _, image_files = a
  current_json_dir, _, json_files = b
  if len(image_files) != len(json_files):
    # Do whatever you want
```